# Pandas ValueError on df.join(), then TypeError on pd.concat()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm sure I have a simple error here but I'm not seeing it.  Maybe a fresh pair of eyes can pick it out in a minute or two.  I've been working on various solutions for a while now and I need some help.

I have a Pandas dataframe and I'm attempting to add a newly created calculated column to the dataframe based on an existing column in that dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('mydata.csv')
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')

# calculate Simple Moving Average with a 20 day window
sma = df_train.close.rolling(window=20).mean()

res = df_train.join(sma, on='date', how='left', lsuffix='_left', rsuffix='_right')
print(res)
```

> ValueError: You are trying to merge on datetime64[ns] and int64
>   columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

Ok, so I tried using pd.concat:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('mydata.csv')
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')

# calculate Simple Moving Average with 20 days window
sma = df_train.close.rolling(window=20).mean()

frames = [df_train, sma]
res = pd.concat(frames)
print("Printing result of concat")
print(res)
```

> TypeError: concat() missing 1 required positional argument: 'objs'

What positional argument is needed?  I can't figure this out based on the research and documentation I've seen online.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's the output of `print(df.date.head(3))` and `print(sma.date.head())`?

Comment: not sure where `df_train` came from in the code, but im assuming you left it out by accident. why dont you just create a new column on the dataframe. `df['20_SMA'] = df.close.rolling(window=20).mean()`. if you are worried about NA values just use `df.dropna(inplace=True)`

Comment: Yes, I left out df_train = df earlier.  Thanks Randy.  That did the trick. I hope this helps somebody else as well.